# Permission for Public Feed API

Tags: facebook, api, public, hashtag, facebook-feed

I'm working on a project which needs the capability to find posts which are using a specific hashtag.
Looks like I need access to the Public Feed API. 
Did I understand this correctly?

If no: what API do I need instead?

If yes: whats the best way to contact Facebook for getting permissions on the API.

Greets,

nougatbyte

Answer (score 0):

Public Feed API is not available anymore (since API V 2.0). You can't search for tags and there is no request for permission to access it.

Media Solution Partners can probably provide similar (paid) functionality:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/partners